Do any languages assign gender to inanimate objects based on material properties like flexibility instead of shape?
In the Palikur language of Brazil, inanimate objects that are solid and strong all have feminine gender, while objects that are soft, fragile or flexible have neuter gender. (There are no inanimate objects of male gender.) Are there any other languages whose gender systems are affected by material properties like flexibility instead of geometrical shape?

Noun genders are really just a particular way of thinking about noun classes. And noun classes frequently classify inanimate nouns in lots of different ways.

What’s interesting here is that the genders are also related to biological sex. So they are not just noun classes, but the question is whether there is some cognitive association between certain types of inanimates and female sex.

I would recommended taking a look at Corbett, 1991, Gender. It has descriptions of many gender systems, grouped by whether the classification is primarily based on semantics or morphology/phonology.
If I remember correctly, there are systems where long, inflexible objects like sticks tend to be masculine, while shorter and plumper objects tend to be feminine. Ket may have a system with some associations like this (check Corbett’s index).
These associations are commonly explained by some similarity between the inanimate object and prototypical males/females. For instance, males tend to be longer, and females have wider hips. There is quite some variation in the different associations gender systems make though, so these explanations are always somewhat ad hoc.
